# Bullet Point Position In An Unordered List Not Working With A Textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, html-lists, wysiwyg

Normally, when I create an unordered list in HTML, it will align the bullet point to the top of the text. If I put an input element inside the li element, then it will align in the middle. This is all fine, except that when I add a text area element it aligns towards the bottom of it. Here's an example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Bullet is at <br/>the top</li>
    <li><input type="text" value="Bullet is centered" /></li>
    <li><textarea placeholder="Bullet is too low" ></textarea></li>
</ul>
```

The above code looks like this in Firefox v60.0:

[Image Display in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiWIF.png)

I'm creating a WYSIWYG editor for a specific application. It is mostly finished and the last thing I need to do is get the bullet point behind the textarea to go to the top rather then the bottom.

So far I've tried changing vertical-align to center, baseline, and top to the li element in the unordered list with no success. I have also changed the list-style-position to inside and outside. My searches for anyone else who encountered this problem haven't turned anything either. The only thing I can think might work, would be positioning the li elements relatively and then adding an absolutely positioned bullet point image, but I'd prefer that to be a last resort.

Does anyone have any ideas? I need a solution that only uses HTML, CSS, and not sure why you'd need it, but Javascript is okay (not JQuery). It only needs to work in later Firefox versions. Cross-browser compatibility is not needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your `textarea` to `display: block`

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Bullet is at <br/>the top</li>
    <li><input type="text" value="Bullet is centered" /></li>
    <li><textarea placeholder="Bullet is too low" ></textarea></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad this was a simple fix. I had figured that textareas were already displayed as a block element, but it appears to be displayed inline by default if I'm not mistaken.